# HTTP Packet Decode

Tags: http, httphandler

Can I use the libpcap C API to read/decode/understand HTTP packets?

Answer (score 0):

No. libpcap just captures packets, it's up to you to do something with the data inside the packets.

One very good packet analyzer is [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Maybe that does something you want.